# Dynamic GemFire Region Creation with PCC

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

I am using Pivotal GemFire 9.1.1 through Pivotal Cloud Cache 1.3.1 and ran into the following error while using the `@EnableClusterConfiguration` SDG annotation:

```
2018-11-17T16:30:35.279-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'gemfireClusterSchemaObjectInitializer'; nested exception is org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerOperationException: remote server on ac62ca98-0ec5-4a30-606b-1cc9(:8:loner):47710:a6159523:: The function is not registered for function id CreateRegionFunction
2018-11-17T16:30:35.279-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:184)
```

Finally, I ran into this post - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/issues/15

Is there any other annotation I can use with *Spring Boot 2+* which will help me with GemFire Region creation, dynamically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, NO; there is no other way to currently and "dynamically" push cluster/server-side configuration from a Spring/GemFire cache client to a cluster of PCC servers running in PCF, using SDG/SBDG at the moment.

This is now because of this underlying issue as well, SBDG [Issue #16](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/issues/16) - "*HTTP client does not authenticate when pushing cluster config from client to server using @EnableClusterConfiguration with PCC 1.5.*"

For the time being, you must manually create Regions (and Indexes) using the [documentation](https://docs.pivotal.io/p-cloud-cache/1-4/using-pcc.html#create-regions) provided by PCC.

I am sorry for any inconvenience or trouble this has caused you.  This will be resolved very soon.

This does work in a local, non-managed context, even when starting your cluster (servers) using *Gfsh*.  It just does not work in PCF using PCC, yet.

Regards.